# starter application react native error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I just started with react-native development on IOS and want to get my feet wet.

I did the following:

```
 react-native init trail
```

and I opened the trail starter project in xcode and hit run. There were several small issues I fixed already including upgrading watchman, upgrading OSX. Currently the logs do not show any errors.

While the logs show that the packager runs, the build failed on XCode. A lot of errors showed up with the files in the Library folder. Many of them show up as Parse Issues, Semantic Issues.

I'm currently using Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. Why did the started app fail to build?

Here are some code snippets of the errors:

[code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRP2w.png)

[code snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btUXA.png)

Comment: Can i see code snippets?

Comment: i took two screenshots thanks

Comment: Have you edited the code?

Comment: no i have not done any editing to the code

Comment: From Where did you get the code. did you converted it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your versions of node, npm and xCode.
2. Run 'react-native init yourAppName';
3. Run in yourAppNameFolder 'npm i' - to install all needed dependencies, which may be missing;
4. Run 'open yourAppNameFolder/ios/yourAppName.xcodeproj' where appFolder - folder which one have been initialized by command 'react-native init'.

This should help, and one more suggestion - don't touch this bloody xcode, better to run the app from the shell.